# Standard deviation in regression trees

Tags: regression, machine-learning, normal-distribution, cart

In a regression tree, it is often assumed that each leaf is a Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma)$, where $i$ is the index the leaf. Is $\sigma$ calculated as the standard deviation *within a leaf* or the standard deviation for the dataset?

If a tree is grown such that each leaf contains one instance (as is the case for bagged trees) then the *within leaf* calculation seems ill-posed. However, using the whole dataset seems like it could induce a lot of bias.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, the standard deviation $\sigma$ is calculated within a leaf. This is because, at each split, we are trying to minimise the sum total of the **population** variance, where the population is the collection of target values at each leaf. It is not ill-posed (in the case where a leaf contains one instance) as we are not trying to calculate a *sample* variance as an estimate for the population variance. For the case where a leaf contains one target value $\{y\}$, the mean is $y$ and the variance is zero.